# How to preview an HTML email before sending it. C#

Tags: c#

I have developed a program which is sending HTML email using mail definition class. 
Is it possible to preview the email before sending it.

Here is a piece of code using `mailDefinition` :

```
 MailDefinition mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
 mailDefinition.BodyFileName = "C:/Html_Email.htm";
 mailDefinition.From = "kami@gmail.com";

 ListDictionary ldReplacements = new ListDictionary();

ldReplacements.Add("<%NearTeaser%>", "<b> Welcome to <b>" + nearteaser + "<b>");
ldReplacements.Add("<%Content%>", fulltext);
ldReplacements.Add("<%Weitere%>", "We have these offers for you: " + Weitere); 

MailMessage mailMessage = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(mailTo, ldReplacements, new System.Web.UI.Control());

mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "hostname";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Every thing is working fine. I am curious if it is possible to preview the email before sending it.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on *what* is sending it.. a web application?  Windows Forms?  WPF?  Try and provide *some* effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending email display the contents of ldRelacements in a multitext box or in a panel/div.

MailDefinition class allows to create email messages from text files or strings.

Please go through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition(v=vs.110).aspx. It will give you some insights about MailDefinition class and examples.